# how to re-open google chrome's developer mode 's message remind?

Tags: google-chrome

the system is WIN10,  when I open the chrome's developer mode , a little while,there comes out a message ,similarly like this :"we have chinese version" , I want to look for details, but unfortunately I click " Do not show this again".
The position  is this picture's red character's position.
[this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O88fV.jpg)

So I want to know how to get this message again, and where to setup the reminder?

Thank you so much!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Reset Chrome settings to default
On your computer, open Chrome.
At the top right, click More Settings. Advanced. On Chromebook, Linux, and Mac: Click Reset settings Restore settings to their original defaults. Reset settings. On Windows: Click Reset and cleanup Reset settings to their original defaults. Reset settings.

This usually works for me :) let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exact message are you referring to, but you can configure much of aspects of developer console via settings (`Shift + ?` on my computer or clicking on cog icon in top right corner)

[image: Developer console settings]

There is also `Restore defaults and reload` button which should get rid of anything you overridden before:

[image: Reset button]